# How can I tell node to use a particular installed package version?

Tags: node.js, npm

If I have versions 1.1 and 1.2 of package foo installed on my system, and bar.js requires package foo, is there a way to invoke `node bar.js` so that node uses version 1.1 of foo?

Comment: Don't use global npm modules unless you have to — then you can specify a specific version for each package in your package.json.

Comment: @brandonscript does node use the version specified in ./package.json? i though only npm used this when installing.

Comment: Yes – https://semver.npmjs.com

Comment: @brandonscript lol. lots of googling didn't find that, possibly because i was googling with the assumption it wasn't the case.

Answer (score 1):

NPM packages that are local to the project stay in `node_modules` and don't update unless you explicitly update them yourself. You can use NPM's semantic versioning to manage the granularity of your dependencies on a *per-project* basis. Here's a semver cheat sheet: https://semver.npmjs.com/

With that in mind, where this breaks down is if you're installing modules *globally* (which you should **not** be doing unless the package owner tells you to, e.g. Grunt or Angular-CLI). If you are using global modules and you don't need to be, you should fix that ;)

If you find that semantic versioning is causing conflicts for dependencies *within* your project (e.g. foo requires bar 1.0 and faa requires bar 1.1) OR you are concerned about the risk of breaking dependency changes, take a look at [Yarn](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yarn).